# Menu links highlight on one-page webiste, when standing on a current sector (id).

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I made an option to highlight the active menu link, when scrolling to the appropriate sector (id) of the one-page website. However, it is not working perfectly, as when I click on one opf the menu links in the navbar, sometimes it just jumps over to another one.

Can anybody help me resolve this?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

//Smoothscroll
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");

    $('a').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var target = this.hash,
        menu = target;
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
    }, 500, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });
});
});

function onScroll(event){
var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
$('#myNavbar a').each(function () {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + 
      refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $('#myNavbar ul li a').removeClass("active");
        currLink.addClass("active");
    }else{
        currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
});
}
```

Sorry for an ugly code, as I just copy-paste-ed it here, without fixing it.

To see what am I talking/thinking about, you can look at my website on vlad095.github.io

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + 
          refElement.height() > scrollPos)
```

to

```
if (refElement.position().top + 20 <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + 
          refElement.height() - 20 > scrollPos)
```

you can play with that 20 and change it to what ever is best for you.